# NuxtJS 3 $fetch refuse to connect to local server

Tags: laravel, vue.js, nuxtjs3

I am new to Nuxt3. I tried to connect my Nuxt3 app to my backend site which is built with Laravel. My frontend URL is http://localhost:3000 and my backend is http://localhost:8000. When I connect to http://localhost:8000/api/names using "useFetch" inside a component, it runs fine. But when I do it inside server/api/names.js using $fetch, it shows a 500 (Internal server error).

This runs fine (sample.vue)

```
const getNames = async () => {
    let { data } = await useFetch('http://localhost:8000/api/names')
    console.log(data);
}
```

This does not

(sample.vue)

```
const getNames = async () => {
    let { data } = await useFetch('/api/names')
    console.log(data);
}
```

(/server/api/names.js)

```
export default defineEventHandler(async (event) => {
  const { data } = await $fetch("http://localhost:8000/api/names");
  return { data };
});
```

Here's the code on my Laravel app inside api.php (http://localhost:8000/api/names)

```
Route::get('/names', function (){
    $users_name = User::all()->pluck('name');
    return response()->json(['names' => $users_name]);
});
```

Here's the error that shows when I go to network tab

`message: "terminated"`

`stack: "<pre><span class=\"stack internal\">at Fetch.onAborted (node:internal/deps/undici/undici:11000:53)</span>\n<span class=\"stack\">at Fetch.emit (node:events:513:28)</span>\n<span class=\"stack internal\">at Fetch.terminate (node:internal/deps/undici/undici:10272:14)</span>\n<span class=\"stack internal\">at Object.onError (node:internal/deps/undici/undici:11095:36)</span>\n<span class=\"stack internal\">at Request.onError (node:internal/deps/undici/undici:6477:31)</span>\n<span class=\"stack internal\">at errorRequest (node:internal/deps/undici/undici:8440:17)</span>\n<span class=\"stack internal\">at Socket.onSocketClose (node:internal/deps/undici/undici:7895:9)</span>\n<span class=\"stack\">at Socket.emit (node:events:513:28)</span>\n<span class=\"stack\">at TCP.<anonymous> (node:net:313:12)</span></pre>"`

`statusCode: 500`

`statusMessage: ""`

`url: "/api/names"`

I tried to restart both servers hoping that doing this would fix the issue but the problem still persists. Also searched if it has something to do with CORS but it connects when I call the api inside a component.

Comment: Does it work with static data in the server route (rather than with `$fetch`)?

Comment: Yes, it does. Oh and one more thing. It also works when I call dummy json data from jsonplaceholder typicode site. The error only shows when I call an api from the laravel server. But it works when I call inside a component so I'm really confused.

Comment: Lol what? Does it work with Postman/curl?

Comment: I just tried with both and it works. Sorry man, I don't know what's going on lol. Maybe I should just stick with Inertia.js for now.

Comment: Maybe try with a regular `fetch` rather than `$fetch`?

Comment: I downgraded my NodeJS version to v16.19.0 and that seemed to fix the issue. Thanks for the help kissu I appreciate it :)

Comment: Hm, Nuxt3 is not supposed to work well with Node 16. Maybe try another version of Node 18?

Comment: @WellyWellington - I've literally got the exact same problem - can fetch from a remote api, but it won't fetch from a local api built with laravel. It's not a cors issue becuase the api works fine through postman. Was your only option downgrading node?

Answer (score 1):

Changing "localhost" to "127.0.0.1" in the fetch URL worked for me. Using Node 18.14.

Comment: Thank you so much! This did the trick for me. Not sure why though. Does anyone know?

Answer (score 0):

I had exactly the same problem yesterday and luckily I found a solution without having to downgrade the version of NodeJS because Nuxt3 does not work well under version 16 of Node.

First use Laragon for your Laravel Backend. Laragon automatically creates Hostname for projects ex: `laravelbackend.test` if the project folder is called `"laravelbackend"`.

Then on the file `(/server/api/names.js)` replace `localhost:8000/api` with `laravelbackend.test/api`

```
export default defineEventHandler(async (event) => {
  const { data } = await $fetch("http://laravelbackend.test/api/names");
  return { data };
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Upgrading my Node.js version from **Node 18** to **Node 20** worked for me.